# What happens if I call C's read() multiple times?

Tags: c, io

The documentation is quite vague about this. If I call C's `read()` function multiple times, I have to pass a number of bytes that I wish to read each time. But how do I know what the starting index will be? For example:

`n = read(fd, *buffer, 10)
 n2 = read(fd, *buffer, 10)`

The first call to `read` will read 10 bytes of the file with file descriptor `fd` into `buffer`. But when I call it again, will it read the exact same thing, or will it read the *next* 10 bytes? I don't really think that would make sense, but I can see no way to define a desired starting index otherwise.

Comment: @John3136 That's not how you do portable software.

Comment: Documentation is pretty clear on this: *the file offset is incremented by the number of bytes read*.

Comment: @FUZxxl Are you trying to tell me `read()` isn't portable in whether or not it returns the same bytes over and over?

Comment: @John3136 `read()` is portable (as in, specified in POSIX), but you don't write portable software by trying out what's happening. Things that work one way on one platform may very well do something else on another platform. The portable approach is to consult the relevant documentation and standards to find out what you can and cannot assume about the behaviour of a function.

Comment: @John3136 For example, about half of the flags to `open()` in Linux are non-standard. If you believe your code using `open()` is portable just because it works on Linux, you are misguided. The same thing applies to some behaviour of `read()`, see the POSIX page I linked to.

Comment: @FUZxxl I work multiple OSes. I use `read` on files and sockets. I know about portability. You don't need to teach me. OP's question is at such a basic level that I think answering it by experiment is applicable to their situation. You don't have to agree. Everyone is entitled to their own opinion no matter how wrong it is ;-)

Comment: I would suggest there is value in both reading the manpages/standards AND writing test programs to verify your reading comprehension.

Comment: Note: `read()` may read less than 10 bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operating system keeps track of the "current position" in the file. When you open the file, this will be the start of the file. Every time you call `read`, you read some bytes from the current position, and also advance the current position. You can use [`lseek`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/lseek) to change the current position.

Note that `read` also works with things that *don't* have a current position, like pipes and sockets. Since reading from those will always return the next bit of data you haven't read yet, this makes them consistent with how files work (except that you can't use `lseek`).

Answer (score 2):

The `read(fd, buf, len)` function will advance the offset stored in the file description referrred to by `fd` by `len`. Every time you call `read` or `write`, action takes place at that offset and the offset is incremented afterwards. You may be able to manually reposition the offset with `lseek()` depending on what kind of file `fd` refers to.

There is also a pair of functions `pread()` and `pwrite()` that do not modify this offset, instead you have to explicitly pass an offset to the function. Please notice that `pwrite()` is broken with respect to `O_APPEND` on Linux.

For more details, read what IEEE 1003.1, 2013 edition (POSIX.1 2008) says about [read()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html).

Comment: I thought it was `pwrite()` that's broken in Linux?  See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html#BUGS